# 64-bit outlook link no longer being found with python script - SUBPROCESS.Popen()

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, python

I used to execute a script that at the end would distribute an e-mail using Microsoft Outlook and a custom form. I found a website that told you how to create a custom form, insert some VBA script into it and then create a an 'application' link that you could double click to send the e-mail. You would then add a small line of code to a already existing python script that would execute the application and therefore send the e-mail automatically. However, the other day I had my IT department upgrade my Microsoft Office suite from 32-bit to 64-bit and I can no longer send the e-mail. Whenever I execute the script a popup window shows up saying that the file cannot be located.

I modified the code attempting to open another file instead and it works, meaning that the issue is with Microsoft Outlook solely. Please let me know if there is a way I can work around this without having to revert back to 32-bit Microsoft Office since the upgrade is going to help me in other ways. Below is a small snippet of code for reference:

```
Import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("start /B Z:\\Maps\\Base_GIS_Data\\SCRIPTS\\Sales_Performance\\eMail_Script.lnk", shell=True)
```

UPDATE: Python 2.7 being used, IDE: PyCharm 3.4.1

Comment: Does double clicking the eMail_Script.lnk work for you? If it doesn't you'll need troubleshooting help with that, and not the python part of the issue.

Comment: Double clicking the .lnk application does work. I then assumed that it isnt working because maybe the python add-in installed is 32-bit VS 64-bit???

Comment: Nobody has anything for me?????

Comment: Does running `start /B Z:\\Maps\\Base_GIS_Data\\SCRIPTS\\Sales_Performance\\eMail_Script.lnk` from the command prompt work successfully? Does starting other things on the Z: drive from python work? That is, have you verified that python sees the drive mapping and can access the .lnk?

Comment: I tried running the start script in the terminal inside of PyCharm 3.4.1 and it said the system cannot find the file. I then was able to successfully open a separate file on the same network. This makes me believe it has to do with the 32-bit/64-bit issue.